# Javascript string in C# escaping issue

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

I am having a problem with javascript.

The javascript gets created dynamically on a C# winforms project as a string.

The actual javascript code gets generated fine and all the double quotes get escaped as they should. My problem comes in when I assign a string inside of this function such as

```
string js = "eval(\"var someVar = 'someValue'\");";
```

So I end up with a string in the browser as

```
eval(\"var someVar = 'someValue'\");
```

The problem is the "\" that is escaping the " in front of 'someVar'. It gets put in automatically in C#. That makes the string invalid when trying to execute the actual function in a browser. Any ideas how I might go about solving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the C-notso-# code that produces this atrocious JavaScript? There isn't really a good reason to use `eval`. Does C# have a JSON-encoder, or is there a library that does this for you?

Comment: I am not really using eval. The example suffices in showing the final product. And yes, I can change the code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How do you pass the string to the web?

Comment: The javascript gets saved inside of <script> tags inside of an iFrame. The iFrame string gets sent to the front view and the entire frame appended to a predetermined child.

Answer (score 1):

You can check HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode Method if you are using .net 4 or later framework

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need eval. This is how I do what you're trying to do.

Step 1: set up a Literal object on your aspx page. I put the literal in a hidden div.

```
<div style="display:none;" id="TheDiv">
   <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TheLiteral" />
</div>
```

Step 2: inject the value in the literal into the C# code behind file.

```
TheLiteral.Text = SomeValue;
TheLiteral.Text = SomeValue.ToString(); // in case SomeValue is not a string
```

Step 3: get the value from the client:

```
var SomeVar = $('#TheDiv').text();
$('#TheDiv').remove();
```

For sure, there are other ways of doing it as well but this method works for me.

Comment: I am not using asp.net, but rather winforms.

Comment: I don't understand: where's the javascript running? Are you building a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: It's not running anywhere. Rather the javascript get created in a desktop application, but then will at a later stage run on a web application.

Comment: This sounds like a really weird plan. Anyway, another alternative would be to create a JSON string that you can parse in javascript: "{SomeVar:" + SomeValue + "}";